# Handling $ sign in username in lftp

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, lftp

I'm trying to deploy website to Azure App Service from an *Alpine Linux* box using *lftp*. The username is always in the form `usr\$usr`. For whatever reason *lftp* (version `4.7.6-r0`) is using only `usr\` part. The command I'm using is using variables.

```
lftp -c "set ssl:verify-certificate on && set ftp:ssl-force on && open -u $FTP_USER,$FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_SERVER && mirror -vvv -R -e --scan-all-first --transfer-all --overwrite --parallel=24 ./wwwroot $FTP_LOCATION"
```

So the `$` in username is not actually part of the command, but inside variable, thus the `$usr` is not treated as variable.

Looks like it's the combination of `\` and `$` that somehow confuses *lftp*. Any ideas how to pass credentials differently? Or escape it.

I tried also `ftp://$FTP_USER:$FTP_PASSWORD@$FTP_SERVER`, but that didn't help. Same with `usr\\$usr` or `usr\\\$usr`.

Comment: Just curious - do you *have* to use ftp for deployment? There are many other options...

Comment: Well, there's a _webdeploy_ and that's it. I wouldn't call it many.

Comment: Now *I'm* confused: We're talking Web Apps, are we not? Aside from ftp, Web Apps are integrated with VSTS / git / github / onedrive / dropbox / bitbucket. I'd call that *many.*

Comment: Yes, Web Apps. But the other types are let's say _pull_ types. Only _ftp_ and _webdeploy_ is _push_ type. And this app has already CI/CD running (with some quite custom steps) so I would have to rewrite it completely to i.e. _VSTS_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not `lftp`, but GitLab CI. The *dollar sign* needs to be quoted there by another `$`. I described it [here](https://blog.cincura.net/233595-handling-a-dollar-sign-in-a-username-for-deploying-azure-web-app-via-ftp-on-gitlab-ci/).

Comment: its been two hours and I can not surpass: "mirror: Login failed: 530 User cannot log in." I am trying randomly by now... funny that from FileZilla I can connect with app USR/PWD, testing from a local mac computer before sending it into gitlab also... any ideas why I get refused immediatelly (I used your lftp command)? Thanks, V.

Answer (score 0):

Lftp itself does not expand shell variables, so most probably the substitution happens when you assign to the FTP_USER variable.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I was focused on `lftp`, but the problem is GitLab CI. The `$` needs to be quoted. I wrote the whole story here: https://blog.cincura.net/233595-handling-a-dollar-sign-in-a-username-for-deploying-azure-web-app-via-ftp-on-gitlab-ci/ .